# Is it possible to have same Android Application with or without facebook login?

Tags: android, facebook, authentication, facebook-login

I want to make the application available in the Google/ third party market which can be used by anyone without using any login details on the cellphone. I want to add the same application to facebook later wherein people can access through Facebook. Basically, I want to allow users to directly access without login from their cellphone and Facebook users to access the application from Facebook Apps/Store/newsfeed.

I know we can add facebook login code. But, doing this will mean even the users accessing from Google Store or third party has to log in from facebook? Will it be possible to allow both ways?

Answer (score 2):

In you case, yes it is possible.

With a simple conditional check you can activate or disable any feature of your app.

You didn't mentioned the language you are using to develop the app.

However, with an if condition check if platform is android or facebook.

- If it is android, don't ask for login,
- if it is facebook, get the
  user details.

Simple, isn't it?

Comment: I will be using Java language.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible you can use build flavors for that 
for more follow below link

[Build variants](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/build-variants)